# Writing interactions for pact-js-mocha that respond with an error

Tags: node.js, pact

I've been working through the pact-js-mocha example and I'm having some difficulty verifying an interaction when the expected response is an error. This is the interaction I would like to verify:

```
PactConsumer(PactOpts, function () {

  addInteractions([{
    state: 'i have a list of projects',
    uponReceiving: 'a bad request for projects',
    withRequest: {
      method: 'get',
      path: '/projects'
    },
    willRespondWith: {
      status: 400,
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
      body: { reply: 'this is a 400' }
    }
  }])


  verify('a 400 is returned', expectError, function (result, done) {
    expect(JSON.parse(result)).to.eql({ reply: 'this is a 400' })

  })

  finalizePact()

})
```

However I'm not sure about the expectError() function. In the examples this returns a superagent request however when the status is set to 400 in the interaction the method seems to throw the error.

I've tried a few things but it has mostly been trail and all been error (things like using supertest to create a request and expecting on it's result).

Thanks for your help

Comment: This looks like an issue with the pact Mocha UI. From memory this is linked to a WIP pact version instead of current 2.x branch which has some unusual behavior we removed. Can you please raise an issue and we can discuss there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible work around that has done the job for me:

```
const chai = require('chai');
const expect = require('chai').expect;
chai.use(require('chai-as-promised'));
var should = chai.should();
const request = require('superagent');
const commons = require('./specCommons');

const EXPECTED_BODY = {
      "errors": [
          "invalid request"
      ]
};
const SENT_BODY = {
    "body": null
};

PactConsumer(commons.PACT_OPTS, function() {

  addInteractions([{
      state: 'the state',
      uponReceiving: 'an invalid request,
      withRequest: {
          method: 'POST',
          path: commons.PATH,
          headers: commons.REQUEST_HEADERS,
          body: SENT_BODY
      },
      willRespondWith: {
          status: 400,
          headers: commons.RESPONSE_HEADERS,
          body: EXPECTED_BODY
      }
  }]);

  function requestTemplate() {

      return request.post('http://localhost:' + commons.PACT_OPTS.providerPort + commons.PATH)
          .set(commons.REQUEST_HEADERS)
          .send(SENT_BODY)
          .catch((error) => {
              return JSON.stringify(error);
          });
  }

  verify('a 400 error is returned for an invalid request', requestTemplate, 
  function(result, done) {
          result = JSON.parse(result);
          Promise.all([                
       expect(result.response.text).to.equal(JSON.stringify(EXPECTED_BODY)),
       expect(result.status).to.equal(400)
          ]).should.notify(done);
      });

  finalizePact();
});
```

Where the specCommons.js looks like:

```
module.exports = {
  PATH: 'api endpoint',
  REQUEST_HEADERS: {
      'Accept': 'application/json'
  },
  RESPONSE_HEADERS: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
  },
  PACT_OPTS: {
      consumer: 'our consumer',
      provider: 'our provider',
      providerPort: 1234
  }
};
```

Comment: I've accepted this answer for the time being as it is the only answer and it does the job - but if anyone has more to add that would be helpful I'm sure.